# Mongorepository.save() not updating a field in 1-2 attempt

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, crud

I have the following piece of code Which doesn't seem to work in 1-2 attempt after that it works.

```
Merchant merchant = merchantRepository.findOne(merchantBean.getId());
merchant.setFeatures(abc.getFeatures());
merchantRepository.save(merchant);
```

When run above written lines field `Features` doesn't get updated in 2-3 attempts. After that, it works fine. Is there something I need to change?

Thanks in advance!
Software Stack:
1) Spring boot 1.5.4.RELEASE
2) Spring data
3) MongoDb 3.2.2

P.S: I have tested this case multiple times. `Features` is a `List` of `String` type.

Comment: *Features doesn't get updated in 2-3 attempts. After that, it works fine.* ... could you please elaborate what do you mean here?

Comment: I mean suppose previously there were 7 features and I want to chang it to 5 features to replace 7. those 7 features still persist. and new Features doesn't get reflected in DB.

Comment: For one, it sounds as if you are looking for `replace` operation. Second, not getting reflected in the DB without any failure/error is surprising to me as well. `save` shall ideally perform an `upsert` here.

Comment: I am also surprised that why I am not getting any error. Also, I have debugged  `merchant` object before saving it shows 5 new features only which I am inserting. Is there any possible workaround?

Comment: Also, i hope in the line of code `merchant.setFeatures(abc.getFeatures())` the `abc.getFeatures()` are actually updated features, since there is not relation shown for them with `merchant`'s features in the code.

Comment: Indeed they are new features coming from a `RequestBody`. I also verified that in the browser console to make sure that the right parameters are sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186406/discussion-between-jayesh-choudhary-and-nullpointer).